# Xamarin.Forms access to Android and IOS SDK functions for Camera

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.forms, sdk

I'm working on Xamarin.Forms app and have a specific scenario:
I want to application use the Native sdk functions depending on phone OS(Android and IOS) and phone Camera functionalities(ex. for scanning document).
I tried something with:
 `public Interface ICameraAccess`
and Import in Android and IOS with `assembly`, but i cant find a implementation and functionalities of the platform specific functions for device Camera in Android and IOS.

***How can access to SDK functionalities?***

Comment: search "xamarin android camera api" and "xamarin ios camera api".  Or look at the source for the Xamarin Forms MediaPIcker in github

Comment: There should be no difference reading a camera on any windows machine except the resolution/size (number of pixels) can be different. So an application has to support the size on the machine you are using.  Windows requirements are for the manufacturer to be compatible with Windows which means there is a driver the reads the device and formats the driver to meet windows specifications.  So reading a camera from any manufacture should work with any application that supports the device resolution/size.